# Non-contiguous cells causing problems in UDF

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions, standard-error

I've written a user defined function in for Excel that adds the Standard Error Function. The function works well, except when using it on non-contiguous cells or ranges.
For example: Function works on cells (`A1:A200`), but not if used on cells (`A1,B2,C3,D14`)

From what I can tell, the problem is coming from the line `Size = WorksheetFunction.Count(numbers)` when it's later used in the denominator.

```
  Option Explicit

Function StdErr(numbers As Range) As Double
    Dim StdDev As Double
    Dim Size As Integer

    StdDev = WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(numbers)
    Size = WorksheetFunction.Count(numbers)

    StdErr = StdDev / Sqr(Size)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

It works Ok for me if the formula is entered as

```
=StdError((A1,B2,C3,D14))
```

so that the , is treated as a union operator rather than a parameter separator